# how to test multiple browser(versions) with selenium and junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I just discovered selenium - a great tool!
I plan to run/use selenium-ide generated junit4 code. But I need it to run with many browsers/web drivers.
Is there a junit/java-pattern for this use case? My first idea was to use `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` and provide a List of WebDrivers (the parameter for the class - probably provided as an external file listing browsers and versions?!). Is this a good idea? Is it possible to provide a central `@Parameters` -method to be used by all my Selenium-tests?

What alternatives are there?

Probably it is possible to change the "Format" that Selenium exports to minimize manual changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I do need to switch drivers from time to time, so I did this:

I initialize selenium related stuff in my own Class - called by name of the application and the driver is approached by the getters. When calling my class constructor, I use enum type of driver to initialize with:

```
 private WebDriver driver;
 public TestUI(Environment.DriverToUse drv){
   switch (drv){
        case CHROME:{
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
            File file = new File(TestUI.class.getResource("/chromedriver.exe").toURI());
            System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, file.getAbsolutePath());                
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(service,options);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            break;
        }
        case FIREFOX:{
            FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
            ffProfile.setPreference("browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled", false);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
            driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
            java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Dimension dim = new Dimension((int) screenSize.getWidth(), (int) screenSize.getHeight());
            driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            break;

        }    

public WebDriver getDriver(){
 return driver;
}
```

of course my `Environment` class looks like this

```
public class Environment {
public enum DriverToUse {FIREFOX, CHROME};
// .. and some other stuff, because I need to test on different environments, so I store here Environment URL for example
```

And my test class looks something like this

```
@Before
public static final Environment.DriverToUse USED_DRIVER = Environment.DriverToUse.FIREFOX;

@Test
public void testVersionNumber() throws Exception{

    TestUI testUI= new TestUI(USED_DRIVER);
    WebElement version = testUI.getDriver().findElement(By.id("the Id of element"));
    version.click();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium RC/Selenium Server. These come with the API's you will need to run remote tests in multiple browsers simply. Happy Hunting!

Comment: i just read the docu (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) it seems that the problem remains. with selenium server i also have to instantiate "webdriver" with "capabilities" (a specific browser). at the moment using rc server only implies configuration overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Selenide](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide) library.  It's an open source wrapper for selenium that makes UI testing a breeze. Here's an example test.

```
@Test
public void userCanLoginByUsername() {
    open("/login");
    $(By.name("user.name")).setValue("johny");
    $("#submit").click();
    $(".loading_progress").should(disappear); // Waits until element disappears
    $("#username").shouldHave(text("Hello, Johny!")); // Waits until element gets text
}
```