# How do run each browserdriver based on enum list value?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using the code found in the first answer on this page: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263077/how-to-test-multiple-browserversions-with-selenium-and-junit)

I an able to run this successfully and choose the browser by changing environment USED_DRIVER line for a number of different browsers.

I was wandering if it is possible to run a test runs it through each case once before finishing, i.e. so that it has been tested on each of the selected browsers once I have had a go at using for, and if but havnt been very successful.

**Example Test**

```
driver.get("calc.php");
driver.findElement(By.name("firstnumber")).sendKeys("2");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.name("secondnumber")).sendKeys("2");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Calculate")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.name("save")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is to run a single test multiple times, once for each browser.

There are different ways you can do this...I'll start with the simplest (but hardest to maintain in the future, so make sure you understand each choice before choosing):

**Solution 1:** The simplest way would be to put a for loop around your test.  You will have a List of different WebDrivers that the tests will run on.  It would look something like this:

```
WebDriver[] drivers = new WebDriver[]{firefoxDriver, chromeDriver};
for (WebDriver driver:drivers){
   ...test goes here.....
}
```

The problem with this method is that each test you run will have to have that for loop, and they all will create their own drivers.

**Solution 2:** You could have a central method call each of your tests.  It would look something like this:

```
public void runTests(){
   ...create your drivers here (and the array)...
   for (WebDriver driver: drivers){
      runFirstTest(driver);
      runSecondTest(driver);
   }
}

public void runFirstTest(driver){
    ...code using driver goes here....
}
```

This solves the problem of having a for loop and creating driver instances in every test, but now, whenever you write a new test, you have to add it to this for loop.

**Solution 3:** Another solution exists, using a testing framework.  The two most popular are TestNG and JUnit.  I'm going to assume all of your tests are in the same class, but if you have multiple classes, you will want to have only 1 class have the @DataProvider

```
@DataProvider(name = "drivers")
public provideDrivers(){
   ...create drivers here...
   return new Object[][]{{firefoxDriver},{chromeDriver},....};
}

@Test(dataProvider = "drivers")
public runTest(WebDriver driver){
   ...do stuff with driver here...
}
```

This solution will run every method that has @Test(dataProvider = "...") once for every driver you pass in.  More information is [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

If you have questions, feel free to comment.  I will respond.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I managed to get the first one working well and I do plan on examining the other approaches later but for now the simple, slightly dodgy approach is perfect, however I am now trying to create a class that uses the above approach but I want other test clsses to be able to use it so that I can set different groupings of browsers e.g. all browsers, chrome + ff, ff + ie, chrome + ie and browsers individually and then have all of these callable in the test classes,

Comment: howeveer, I was having an issue on how to run the selected drivers and apply their specific settings e.g.  capabilities, path etc in that class as I could only get FF to run using the browser class and importing it in. I hope i make sense, my teminology maybe off, apologies for that.

Comment: Well, if you are going to put the for() loop around each test, on each of the tests, you can take out the drivers you don't want run.  Your second comment is a whole different question entirely, and one that has been answered quite a few times on Stack Overflow.  Search for "set capabilities on chrome" or whatever browser you want